# Cannot find CLASS in Terminal

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have downloaded an application that is Java.  But I have troubles with running the script.

I have tried "java Main" which properly should run "Main.java"?

But i keep getting this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
```

Here is my terminal try:

```
Last login: Thu Jun 13 17:22:39 on ttys001
new-host:~ jespermadsen$ cd /Users/jespermadsen/Desktop/TimeTakerv2-master
new-host:TimeTakerv2-master jespermadsen$ ls
ChallengeHandler.java       SBUtil.java
ConnectToSock.java      SendToSock.java
CountTime.java          Server part
DownloadFiles.java      SocketAction.java
Login.java          StrangeBase.java
LoginUI.form            TimeTakerRenewedUI.form
LoginUI.java            TimeTakerRenewedUI.java
    Main.java           TingGrabber.java
Protocol.java           decodeChallengeString.java
QStringBuffer.java      jTokenizer.java
RecieveFromSock.java        loginToServer.java
ReplaceHTMLChars.java       n7
RequestSites.java
new-host:TimeTakerv2-master jespermadsen$ java Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile the project. Source files can't be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the code first, using [`javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html).

```
$ javac path/to/Main.java
```

Then,

```
$ java path/to/Main
```